# Dynamic textbox on Boostrap UL - unable to type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have added dynamically a textbox to the bottom of the ul as an option. When I try to type inside the focus is lost. If I remove the `e.stopPropagation()` and the use clicks on the textbox, then the list closes.
How can I type inside my custom textbox `txtCategory` the same way it allows typing on the 'Search' box without closing the list? The `txtCategory` has value '2' when loaded.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLXr6/29/)

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var customOption = "<li class='multiselect4-item multiselect-filter' value='0'><div class='input-group'><input class='xxx' id='txtCategory' value='2'><input type='button' id='btnAddOption' value='Add'></div></li>";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //$("#theChildx").hide();

            $('#example-post-checkboxName').multiselect({
                enableFiltering: true,
                enableClickableOptGroups: true,
        enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true,
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        onDropdownShow: function (select, container) {
            //var siz = parseInt($('#theParentx').height(),5) + parseInt($('#theParentx .multiselect-container').height(), 10) + parseInt($('#theChildx').height(),7);
            //var w = $('#theParentx .multiselect-container').width();
            //$('#theChildx').css({ 'top': siz + "px", 'width': w }).show();
        },
        onDropdownHide: function (event) {
            //$("#theChildx").hide();
        },
                templates: {
                divider: '<li class="multiselect-item divider"></li>',
                liGroup: '<li class="multiselect-item group"><label class="multiselect-group"></label></li>'
                }
            });

            var data = [{
                title: 'First group',
                children: [{ label: 'Cheese', value: 'cheese' , selected: true},
                           { label: 'Tomatoes', value: 'tomatoes', selected: false, "attributes": {"some-attribute": 1, "another-attribute": false } }]
            }, {
                title: 'Second group',
                children: [{ label: 'Mozzarella', value: 'mozzarella' },
                           { label: 'Mushrooms', value: 'mushrooms' }]
            }];

            $("#example-post-checkboxName").multiselect('dataprovider', data);
            $('.dropdown-menu').append(customOption);
        //add actions on dynamically created button
            $('.dropdown-menu').on("click", "#txtCategory", function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
            $('.dropdown-menu').on("click", "#btnAddOption", function () {
               // alert('clicked');
                var theValue = '<option>' + $('#txtCategory').val() + '</option>';
                //$('#txtCategory').val();
                $('#example-post-checkboxName').append(theValue);
                $('#example-post-checkboxName').multiselect('rebuild')
                {
                    $('.dropdown-menu').append(customOption);
                    alert('ok');
                };
                return false;
            });
    });

</script>
```

HTML

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Multiselect</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div id="theParentx">
                <select id="example-post-checkboxName" name="multiselect[]" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3" multiple="multiple" required>
                </select>
                <div id="theChildx" class="dropdown-menu">

               <input />
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `keydown` event along with click to your dynamic `textbox` as below:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on("keydown click", "#txtCategory", function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
});
```

## [`Updated Fiddle Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/bLXr6/30/)